# UITableView selected indexpath value gives wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, nsindexpath

Team,

I have UITableView with which have 50 plus cells count.
width of each cell is 60.

when I scroll up-to 20 cell, then tap on any cell

Its gives the index-path value above cell value not click cell value

Inside CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [[cell checkButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

   -(void)checkButtonAction:(id)sender

    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableview];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

 }
```

If selected index is 21 gives index 20, keeping index count start from zero.

The issue was observed in iOS 10.1 iphone 7 plus device, Not in simulator iPhone 7 plus iOS 10.1 (14B72)

Debugging value
 {length = 2, path = 0 - 14}

NSIndexPath  path should be 0 - 15 but it gives 0 - 14.

Comment: try once replacing sender by ((UIButton*)sender) in convert point;

Comment: if still same problem, then try once with following "[sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.view]"

Comment: @kiran `checkButtonAction:` is your button's touch event ?

Comment: convertPoint?  I'm shocked.

Comment: @sanket Its still same issue.

Comment: @kiran did you try my code ?

Comment: @kiran - I think, you should try Gurinder Batth solution. Its very easy. If I'm not wrong then you have one button in each cell. In CellForRowAtIndexPath, add selector with button using...   YOURBUTTON.tag = indexPath.row;      [YOURBUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I try your code its not working yet.

Comment: event: event must have to pass in add target you forgot this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[YOURBUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(METHODNAME:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

**Button click method**

```
-(IBAction)METHODNAME:(UIButton*)sender event:(id)event
{

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:YOUR_TABLEVIEW];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [YOUR_TABLEVIEW indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
   // your requirement code 
}
```

**If any query about this code then put your comment in answer . 
Good Luck**

**Happy Coding.**

Comment: NSSet *touches = [sender allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

Its crashed not working.

Comment: @kiran what is your problem ? you just comment my code in your code.

Comment: [UIButton allTouches]: unrecognized selector sent to instance this was my crash log

Comment: @kiran i use the above code in my project and its working fine . now just update your question with my code implementation . and also update with error

Comment: The problem is only in iphone 6s device.  I need to know which device you are testing too.  The problem is not appears in simulator, its visible only in iPhone 6s device only.

Comment: @kiran i m not testing in real device now i m working and testing in simulator and its working fine with iphone 6s

Comment: Its working perfectly for me too in simulator iphone 6s 10.1 version.  but in real time in device its failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131121/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-kiran).

Comment: Its working once i have two parameters for the button action.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get `NSIndexPath` in `UIButton` click action method and it's working fine.

Try below code and check:

```
-(void)checkButtonAction:(id)sender

      UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

      CGPoint origin = btn.frame.origin;
      CGPoint touchPoint = [btn.superview convertPoint:origin toView:self.tableview];

      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

}
```

Comment: I changed still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this first of all give the tag number to button in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method

```
yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;


[YOURBUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

and the fetch like this

```
-(void)checkButtonAction:(id)sender

     UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
     int indexPathOfCell = sender.tag;
}
```

Comment: also add [YOURBUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: FYI in this case, we will not able get proper indexPath if table has more than one section.

Comment: @Mahesh - Yes completely agreed. But if questioner have only one section then it will be the great work around for now.

Comment: @Sanket i dont know why but questioner is not responding to anyone for feedback and queries.

Answer (score 1):

As mahesh pointed out a problem with Gurinder Batth solution that its not possible to get section information of indexPath. So I would like to add an answer.

Create new objective-C class inheriting from UITableViewCell. Lets say "MyTableViewCell"

Now modify MyTableViewCell.h by creating IBOutlet of UIButton (by control + click + dragging from UIButton to MyTableViewCell.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyTableViewCell;
@protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)checkButtonClicked:(MyTableViewCell *)cell;
@end

@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MyTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkButton;

@end
```

Then modify MyTableViewCell.m by creating IBAction of UIButton (by control + click + dragging from UIButton to MyTableViewCell.m)

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

- (IBAction)checkButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate checkButtonAction:self];
}

@end
```

Now open your ViewController.m File and implement protocol we have created in MyTableViewCell.h

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MyTableViewCellDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.myTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.myTableView setDelegate:self];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *myTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [myTableViewCell setDelegate:self];

    return myTableViewCell;
}

#pragma mark - MyTableViewCellDelegate method

- (void)checkButtonClicked:(MyTableViewCell *)cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)[self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    // Here access row using "indexPath.row"
    // You can access section using "indexPath.section"
}

@end
```